# How many years ago mahabharata happened?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, krishna, kali-yuga

There are many dates given to mahabharata bit what is the actual date?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.